# How to give call to routing code again in react.js es6?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, DefaultRoute, NotFoundRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
import TaskList from './components/TaskList';
import {fetchData } from './utils/APIUtils';
import config from '../Application.config';

var data={};
    var roleId = $('#hdnRoleId').val();
    fetchData(config.url+'/Roles/'+roleId+'/Tasks.json?TenantId='+config.TenantId).then(function(items)
    {
        console.log('tried to fetch roles');
        console.log(items);
        data =items;
        console.log('inside Routes item fetched');
    }).catch(function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    });

export default (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route handler={TaskList} data={data} >
    </Route>
    {data.map(task =>
              <Route name={task.pageName}  handler={require(task.actualrout)}>
             </Route>
          )}
  </Route>
);
```

I am learning react.js and I got stucked in following issue.
I have given call to API to fetch records.
But, till the records get fetched, it doesn't wait and the code written in "export default" get executed.
Once the record fetched, the again it comes to the same page and sets the records in "data" variable.
But, at that time, the code written in "export default" not get executed.
Because of which, routing is not working.
Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly speaking you should store fetch results in state and rerender:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, DefaultRoute, NotFoundRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
import TaskList from './components/TaskList';
import {fetchData } from './utils/APIUtils';
import config from '../Application.config';

// use React components instead of plain function
export default class Router extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // initial state
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: {}
    }
  }

  // start fetching when component fully initialized 
  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    var roleId = $('#hdnRoleId').val();
    fetchData(config.url+'/Roles/'+roleId+'/Tasks.json?TenantId='+config.TenantId).then(function(items)
    {
        console.log('tried to fetch roles');
        console.log(items);
        // will cause rerender
        self.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data: items
        })
        console.log('inside Routes item fetched');
    }).catch(function(response)
    {
        self.setState({
          isLoading: false
        })
        console.log(response);
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (<div>{'Is loading...'}</div>);
    }
    // by this moment data is loaded if no errors
    return (
      <Route handler={App}>
        <Route handler={TaskList} data={this.state.data} >
        </Route>
        {data.map(task =>
                  <Route name={task.pageName}  handler={require(task.actualrout)}>
                 </Route>
              )}
      </Route>);
  }
};
```